# Testing in Laravel without passing through auth

Tags: php, phpunit, laravel-5.1

I'm trying create a test in Laravel 5.1 but I want to use it without the authorization form.

In my RoleController class I put this in order to :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

I've tried using `use WithoutMiddleWare;` but did'nt work. This is the phpunit output:

```
A request to [http://localhost/nuevo/rol] failed. Received status code [500].
```

Also tried using `$this->withoutMiddleware();` for each test method but that din't work either. This is the phpunit output:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Nothing matched the filter [nombre] CSS query provided for [http://localhost/auth/login].
```

Instead of visit the "nuevo/rol" route the test make a request to "auth/login" as it works using the auth form.

Is there a method to test without using the authorization form or I need to put in my test code the logic to use it?

Comment: Where are you creating your test? In your **`app/Http/Controller`** directory?

Comment: No, in the controller the only thing I do is load in the constructor the auth middleware. My test is on the tests directory and there is where I tried to disable the middleware.

Comment: Ok. Just posted a solution below.

Answer (score 9):

To getting started with [Test-driven development (TDD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) in [Laravel](https://laravel.com), go to the **tests** directory in the root of your installation *(support for [**PHPUnit**](https://phpunit.de/) testing is provided by default so you need not to worry about setting up as this is [already catered for](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing))*.

To create your test, do run the following Artisan Command:

```
php artisan make:test RoleTest
```

The Artisan Command above will create a new RoleTest class in your *tests* directory with the following test case in it (in your newly created **`tests/RoleTest.php`** file):

```
class RoleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

To disable Middleware before running your test, do use **`use WithoutMiddleware;`** as follow so as to apply it to all methods under your RoleTest class:

```
class RoleTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithoutMiddleware;

    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

In case you want to apply the exemption of the middleware to selected methods only make use of **`$this->withoutMiddleware();`** within such methods as follow:

```
public function testExampleWithoutMiddleware()
{
    $this->withoutMiddleware();

    $this->visit('/')
         ->see('Laravel');
}
```

Simply run **`phpunit`** in your command line interface to run your tests.

In the last snippet above, the middleware is disabled for the **`testExampleWithoutMiddleware`** method in which we run a test visit to resource available at the root of your site or application *(based on your installation directory and or provisions made in your **`routes.php`** file)* and check whether it contains the term *`Laravel`*.

**TL;DR**

Simply use **`$this->withoutMiddleware();`** is your method to run PHPUnit test with your middleware disabled; not **`$this->middleware('auth');`** which rather enforces it.

Comment: Maybe I did not explain well. I need the $this->middleware('auth'); in the controller because I want that to access is needed to be logged, and in the test I want to bypass the authorization but I've already tried the both methods that you explain but none of it worked.

Comment: Your question says **without passing through auth**! What do you want to achieve? **Test access to the page with middleware enabled and login as a user** for that purpose or **test access to the page with middleware enabled so as not to login in**?

Comment: This throws de exception PHP Error:  Call to a member function instance() on null in /var/www/html/app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/MakesHttpRequests.php